# Finding least possible difference between 2 sets of objects.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computational-mathematics

Given a set of 100 objects $A$. Each with 10 properties. The property values come from a finite set, $\mathbb{Z}_5$. So the i<sup>th</sup> property of the n<sup>th</sup> object $P(n,i)\in \mathbb{Z}_5$

Now we randomly change 30 properties of the objects in this set.

This means that usually most of the objects will be the same except some of their properties have changed. So it may be easy to find the minimum number of changes.

It may become more difficult when so many properties have changed that it is now quite difficult to pair the objects back to their originals. e.g. the properties of one object have changed to be almost identical to that of another.

Is there a well known algorithm to do this? (It reminds me somewhat of error correction.)

In otherwords we want the least possible set of instructions to turn the set back into the original.

I guess one can think of this as the minimum differences between two matrices which are isomorphic with respect to row permutations. (But not collumn permutations). Whoses entries are from a finite set.

Or the minimum set of differences in coordinates between two sets of vectors if the coordinates are from a finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this as a *linear [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)* on a complete bipartite graph with 100 nodes on each side.  The cost of assigning old object $i$ to new object $j$ is the number of differences among the properties: $$c_{i,j}=|\{k\in \{1,\dots,10\}: P(i,k)\not= P(j,k)\}|$$

Comment: Thanks.  That seems very complicated but I'll check it out! It's funny how most problems we think of have been solved 60 years ago! Well I suppose it's not that strange since that's when computers were invented.

Comment: So first I will end up with an $n\times n$ matrix, $c$, which I will have to permute the rows until the trace is at a minmum. I suppose a brute force algorithm could solve that in $n!$ time. Hopefully your link will help me solve it quicker!

Comment: A $100 \times 100$ linear assignment problem should solve instantly.

Comment: I've no doubt you are right, but the algorithm is quite tricky to implement. (Well for me anyway!) I will have a go at it.

Comment: If you post your data, I’ll run a solver for you, so that you can see the results before you invest a lot of time. Also, you can solve linear assignment problems with a linear programming solver. For this size, it will still be very fast, even without a specialized algorithm.